# Gearman setCompleteCallback slow

Tags: php, gearman

I have a problem.
I perform the tasks in a job that requires a response time
and in setCompleteTasks callback I collect responses to the array and the same callback once out of a hundred I write down all the information in the database

question: why tasks are performed quickly, i know, because I can see this through the utility. 
but callbacks are very slow
for example all the tasks accomplished in 2 minutes, but callbacks still continue to persist for 20-30 minutes

Information like not so much.

Is there another way to gather information as much as possible and put into the database?
Thanks

Comment: Did you consider that the problem might me on the client side? Callbacks will be executed on the client side. If the machine of which client is running does not have sufficient resources processing callbacks might be affected. I would increase job server logging verbosity and determine when exactly callbacks are sent before investigating further.

Comment: Yes, this is true....i save my info now in tasks...thanks